# Installing RediSearch in Azure Cache for Redis

Tags: azure, redis, azure-redis-cache, redisearch

I have an Azure Cache for Redis instance running. I want to perform search on the data stored in the Redis cache using "RediSearch". For using RediSearch, it seems that installation of Redis Stack or a suitable extension is necessary. Is there a way to install this extension to the instance in Azure Cloud.

https://redis.io/docs/stack/search/

Or is there a way to do search without any installations. Please advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One cannot add RediSearch to an existing Azure Cache for Redis instance at this time.

There are several alternatives:

1. You can spin up an Azure Cache for Redis **Enterprise tier** instance with RedisSearch capability enabled
   [Provisioning Enterprise Tier resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryRpk.png)
   [Provisioning RediSearch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9ykr.png)
2. You can spin it up on Redis Cloud, on Azure infrastructure (limited regions)
   [Sign up to Redis Cloud for free](https://redis.com/try-free/)
   [Creating a free database on Redis Cloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZ9NB.png)
3. You can self-manage by [installing Redis Stack](https://redis.io/docs/stack/get-started/install/) on a VM or container instance in Azure

Amiram.